# How to split an array into (equal) chunks

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, chunks

There is a lot of code out there like the below which splits an array into chunks, but I want to split an array into equal chunks (if its an odd number than 1 chunk can be unequal).

Using this example `let array = [21.0, 72.0, 44.0, 56.0, 18, 68.0, 54.0, 35.0, 27.0]`

```
let test = array.chunks(4)
print(test)
```

The below returns: `[[18.0, 21.0, 27.0, 35.0], [44.0, 54.0, 56.0, 68.0], [72.0]]`

However I want it to return: `[[18.0, 21.0, 27.0], [35.0, 44.0, 54.0], [56.0, 68.0, 72.0]]`

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you want a function that can take an Int and split the array into that number of equal chunks?

Comment: @flanker Doubles but yes and account for having an odd count as well

Comment: Very confusing. Why would `array.chunks(4)`, which presumably splits into 4 chunks or found elements per chunk, would return 3 chunks with 3 elements per chunk? What is the significance of 4? Is it the maximum number of chunks or elements?

Comment: good question, not sure why it doesn't chunk as expected. I got it from here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks in any event, i need to return 4 equal chunks (or whatever number you pass in)

Comment: You should read that article again, the argument to the method is the size (number of elements) of a chunk and not the number of chunks. So given you have pasted code in the question that you have misunderstood it’s not clear what your question is now?

Comment: oh I understand that now ‍♂️.